# React Native Random Inner screen flashes for sec before splash screen in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, splash-screen, react-native-ios

I have created a switch navigator between the auth and app screens. The first time it worked fine but after when we use the app for some time it shows a random screen before splash when we open the application again. On Android, it works fine.

Here's my code for app navigator:

```
// Authentication Screens Stack
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        LoginScreen: LoginScreen,
        // Login With Instagram Screen
        LoginInstagram: LoginInstagramScreen,
        RegisterScreen: RegisterScreen,
        ForgotPasswordScreen: ForgotPasswordScreen
},
    {
        // See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig
        headerMode: 'none',
}
);
// Main App Stack from Home Screens
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        DrawerScreen: DrawerNavigator,
},
    {
        // See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig
        headerMode: 'none',
}
);
// Switch Navigator Between Authentication and Home Screens
const SwitchStack = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        Auth: AuthStack,
        App: AppStack,
},
    {
        // See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig
        headerMode: 'none',
}
);

export default createAppContainer(SwitchStack)
```

Here's code for app.js

```
render() {
return (
/**
 * @see https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api/Provider.md
 */
<Provider store={store}>
{/**
 * PersistGate delays the rendering of the app's UI until the persisted state has been retrieved
 * and saved to redux.
 * The `loading` prop can be `null` or any react instance to show during loading (e.g. a splash screen),
 * for example `loading={<SplashScreen />}`.
 * @see https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/PersistGate.md
 */}
<PersistGate loading={<SplashScreen />} onBeforeLift={this.onBeforeLift} persistor={persistor}>
{this.state.gateLifted ? <RootScreen LoginStatus={this.state.isLogin} /> : <SplashScreen />}
{/* {<RootScreen LoginStatus={this.state.isLogin} />} */}
</PersistGate>
</Provider>
)
}
```

I have seen many apps showing this type of behaviour but not found anything about it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The best solution to this will be setting splash on native platforms (android and iOS) separately. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: @rptwsthi is it only related to splash ? as for the first time it works fine but not after that. and It shows me like that in most of the react native applications.

Comment: You can prevent that flashy screen by setting splash on native platform, I have tried that. For your queries, I will need to dig a little..

Comment: thanks @rptwsthi. I will try to set up splash on native and then let's see how it works.